# What does the minus in /Zc:wchar_t- mean?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, wchar-t, cl.exe

Recently I had some linking issues caused by the presence (or absence) of this flag.

`/Zc:wchar_t-`

I've read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s%28VS.71%29.aspx), but they don't mention the trailing minus.  But every discussion of it seems to include it.  What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/Zc:wchar_t-` does the opposite of what `/Zc:wchar_t` does: it causes `wchar_t` to be treated as the same type as `unsigned short`, for compatibility with VC6.

`/Zc:wchar_t-` causes your code to be non-conformant with standard C++, so don't use it unless you must.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I must use it to link to Gecko libs (up to Gecko 7.0 where they stopped using it).